# which DE to use for setting up defaults

Tags: gnome, kde, xfce, desktop, desktop-environment

I'll use awesomewm as my main DE but without installing any actual DE(like KDE, GNOME, XFCE etc) I have to setup too many basic stuff like mouse cursor themes, gtk/qt theme engines and themes, clipboard manager, sound manager, screen manager(like lxrandr, arandr etc.), auto-mounter ...

Now I was thinking if it's possible to just install a DE and get it's settings for those, and then move to awesomewm with all those settings are set up.

Is it possible, and if so, which DE do you recommend for that purpose ?

Comment: Relevant: [Awesome wiki - Quickly setting up awesome with Gnome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome is just a window manager, so the question is a bit odd. You can use for example KDE without kwin, its window manager. That should get you all the other KDE bits and settings.

Answer (score 2):

A window manager is just **part** of a desktop environment. You can use e.g. KDE with Awesome; and [GNOME + Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aGNOME/Openbox) was a common combination some years ago.``

As for what you want to do, but avoiding the large DEs (KDE/GNOME), you can go with e.g.:

- GTK/Qt engines and themes: install `lxappearance`
- auto-mount: `Thunar` running as a daemon can provide this
- clipboard manager: a bunch of choices [at the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Clipboard_Managers)